# WCF Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: c#, wcf, cors

I have an webservice made with WCF, used this getting started tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935(v=vs.110).aspx.

I can't request from ajax, It says that no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. The solutions that I've been seeing on the net are not for me, I don't have a global.asax or web.config file. I've tried adding a global.asax, but it's not among the items I can add to the project.

How do I configure CORS?

Comment: Try looking over this link. I think it will lead to your answer. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/845474/Enabling-CORS-in-WCF

Comment: As with most of the answers out there, it doesn't work for me because I can't add global.asax file in my project. If you know how to, please help, but the usual methods failed.

Comment: Try this? Create a `Global.asax` and then add code the `Global.asax.cs` files `Application_BeginRequest(...)` method. The code should add headers the requests to enable CORS. `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`. Set other headers as required.

Comment: I CAN'T ADD a Global.asax file.

Answer (score 0):

please add this section to your config file:

```
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

and change your method to `*` so you can receive all kind of requests.

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "*"
```